# Prestashop 1.6, conflict: 2 different modules requiring same class, different versions

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, prestashop-1.6, guzzle

In my Prestashop project, I have several modules. In one of them (let's call it "AWS") I installed **AWS SDK** using composer (in PHPStorm), as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html). Composer has "required", among other libraries, "guzzlehttp", updated to its final version.

On the other hand, there is another module (let's call it **"orangeConnect"**) with composer too, that has an earlier version of "guzzlehttp".

The problem lies when I am using AWS SDK in php, inside a php script in the first module. What happens is that it tries to call the URI Composer class and it crashes. Actually, because of the inexistence of one class "UriResolver". The thing is that if I remove "orangeConnect" then AWS SDK connect correctly, which means that the class Uri, in "AWS" is not taken correctly because of "orangeConnect" module. However, I need imperatively to support "orangeConnect" in the project.

How can I, in summary, **solve this conflict between classes in PHP inside Prestashop** and allow each module to include the corresponding valid version of guzzleHttp **without conflicts** of any kind?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the official maintainer of `orangeConnect` module doesn't upgrade the code, there are only 3 methods you can take:

Method 1: You can maintain a copy of your own `orangeConnect` code, and upgrade to latest `Guzzle`. Usually it won't be to difficult because Guzzle's interface are well designed.

Method 2: Get the old Guzzle's code and put it into a new namespace (eg: `OldGuzzle`) and make `orangeConnect` use `OldGuzzle` namespace. You can achieve this by do a global regex replace simply.

Method 3: (Only for big systems) Divide your PHP application to micro-service modules, and isolate `orangeConnect` and `AWS SDK` and make them use different `Guzzle`.